# there is a way to use BotDetect Captcha at Stringboot projecT ?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, botdetect

I want to use BotDetect Catpcha in my SpringBoot application but unfortunately BotDetect requires me to make Captcha Definitions at web.xml. But I do not have web.xml. Do you think is it possible to make servlet definitions at SpringBoot without using web.xml ?

web.xml Sample :

```
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>BotDetect Captcha</servlet-name>
      <servlet class>com.captcha.botdetect.web.servlet.CaptchaServlet</servlet-
   class>
  </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>BotDetect Captcha</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/botdetectcaptcha</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I suggest a read of the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-embedded-container-servlets-filters-listeners-beans). the `web.xml` is just a means to an end, in this case registration of a servlet. The only requirement here is that you register the servlet how you do that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServletRegistration() {
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new CaptchaServlet());
    registration.setUrlMappings(Arrays.asList("/botdetectcaptcha"));
    return registration;
}
```

SpringBoot Application Class